# wsimport not generating the same files as wsgen

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I am using java 6 on a windows 7 box.
I start with a java source file, and run wsgen.bat on it to generate the wsdl and artifacts.
The package name in the generated source code/classes is in xxx.yyy.jaxws.

As a sanity check, I then ran wsimport.bat on the wsdl file generated by wsgen.bat.
Mysteriously, the package name in the generated source code/classes is in xxx.yyy.

That is, instead of generating the exact same source/class files in the same packages, wsimport drops the .jaxws folder in the package name.
Also, the source generated by wsgen does not keep the XXXService.java or .class file, whereas wsimport does.
Has anyone else seen this?  This seems like a bug to me.

I'm using Jax-ws 2.2.5, 07/29/2011.
This is a somewhat old version, so maybe this doesn't happen anymore or it has been fixed.

I have to say I'm thoroughly confused about wsgen and wsimport.
Everything I've read online says that wsgen generates the artifacts from a java file, 
and wsimport generates the artifacts from a wsdl file.  Essentially, they do the exact
same thing, just from different starting points.

What I'm seeing in reality though, is completely different.
wsgen generates class files with correct packages, although it doesn't generate the XXXService.class.
wsimport generates class files with a single package, completely ignoring the package structure of the java files I created for my web service.  wsimport can create a client jar file, something wsgen can't do.

So it seems if I want to access my web service from a java client, I need to use wsimport to create  the client jar file, which I then later need to manually add a MANIFEST.MF file (otherwise, the java compiler does not recognize the classes in the generated client jar file - There are numerous posts all over the web about this).

Comment: Did you see the schemas in the wsdl file?

Comment: What do you mean by that?